# How to get the selection column from a vaadin-gird in vaadin 23?

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin23

I'm using an **ItemClickListener** on my grid and also **multi select mode**. Problem is if you click slightly, next to the selection checkbox the click event is fired and all selections are deleted.

My Idea to work around this is to **check if the event was fired by the selection column**.
I can get the clicked column by `ItemClickEven<>.getColumn()` but I can't find a way to check if this is the selection column. Just getting the first column won't work because reordering is possible. Is there a easy way or do I have to use a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by exploiting a bug in my Vaadin version (23.3.2), that all I needed to is to check if `ItemClickEvent<>.getColumn()` is null. Even it's stated that `getColumn()` shouldn't return null it does for the selection column.